# I have a 404 not found for viewing images

Tags: laravel

My images are not displayed, I have small icons that appear and below the links of the images in question but I do not have the images displayed, and in the console I have this localhost:8000/storage /app/ public /images/0rwZGeyIaXEzNt2jEHMf3713CQdj5EgL7M9Jy1JP.jpg (404 not found)

I want these images to display. I work with Laravel 10

I tried to do the storage:link but still nothing, however I found the images in my public folder but when I go to display them, I get a 404 not found, so I want to display them

Comment: you said you have tried `storage:link`, does the symlink in `public` folder created? what operating system did you use? windows require administrative right to create symlinks..

Comment: yes symbolic link is created, I used windows as operating system

Comment: Lots of spaces in `/storage /app/ public /images/ `

Comment: can you show the code how you are trying to access the image, also share the `config/filesystem.php` and value of `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` from your `.env` file?

Comment: How do you load your images? `asset()`, `mix()` `URL::()`, `http:://localhost/image-path`? Laravel has different type of loading of assets from either storage or public.

Comment: Also, you said you are using laravel 10, is this with starter kit? (uses vite)

Comment: @SouravDutt, access the image                     <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/' . $image->image_path) }}" alt="{{ $image->image_path }}">

Comment: @SouravDutt, mon config/filesystem.php: 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'public' => true,
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

Comment: @SouravDutt, 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ], 'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

Comment: @M.KennethI load them with asset(), I didn't use it Vite

Comment: @user20667848 You didn't shared default `FILESYSTEM_DISK` value from `filesystem.php` and `.env` file. But I guess if you access the file using `asset('storage/' . $image->image_path)` it will work. as it will go into `storage/app/public/` by default. Also in question you mentioned the url of file as `localhost:8000/storage/app/public/images/...` and `images` is missing from the `asset()` method in your comment. 

So I suggest have a look into inside the `storage/app/public/` directory and change the path accordingly inside `asset()` method.

Comment: @SouravDutt filesystem.php : <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

Comment: @SouravDutt :  'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'public' => true,
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

Comment: @SouravDutt: 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

Comment: @SouravDutt: .env: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:YloECfam2YHAzTqtyqkiDQxdPRfMALuwNTeDPgeyr6g=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=knalsonmusic
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

Comment: @SouravDutt: .env.example: BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120